# Django main class for decorators

Tags: python, django, class, program-entry-point

i want to have a main class at my Django Application (i never worked with that before, im new to python/django) where i can use a decorator on like for example: https://github.com/jsocol/django-ratelimit

so i don't have to set this for every single view.
can smb provide an example of how to do this or can expalin where i have to place something like this:

...

thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a main function in a Django app.

If you want something to be applied to every request, you should use middleware.